# Why do I sometimes get corrupted text on Firefox when it loads a webpage?

Tags: firefox, fonts

When I'm in Firefox (52.0.1), my text will occasionally come out garbled and nearly unreadable, as in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

Why does this happen, andd is there anything I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems Microsoft fonts were not installed ,

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Then try again

Comment: Thanks for reply, on the first part of this same center section font is normal. and if i scroll to bottom of the page and scroll up again it's back to normal. Do i still need to install Microsoft fonts.

Comment: Yes , install it

Comment: Still happen, but thanks for reply. Do you have other way.

Comment: I try Chrome. Chrome is not have this problem. I think maybe it's a Firefox problem not Ubuntu.